# Use Holo light theme/style on gingerbread

Tags: android, xml, styles, android-theme

I am currently creating an application for a client. I love the Holo light with dark action bar theme/style but that means that I would have to use API 14 and above. If I set the min API level to 14 then only about 50% of android users will be able to get the application, so I need to have min API level set to 9 (Gingerbread).

Finally the question: is there any way of using the theme/style on gingerbread or even put a Holo light with dark action bar style in Values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library it has `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` (among other things). With it you can almost completely emulate API 14 UI on earlier devices.