# Reference to Activity gets destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity that implements FragmentDelegate and handles all my fragments. My fragments extend from CCPFragment:

```
public class CCFragment extends SherlockFragment{
    public FragmentDelegate m_fragmentDelegate;

    public void setFragmentDelegate(FragmentDelegate fd){
        m_fragmentDelegate=fd;
    }
}
```

When a fragment gets created and added to my view, it receives the Activity and saves a reference to it:

```
fragment.setFragmentDelegate(this);
```

Now, I thought, if an Activity gets destroyed, the fragments get destroyed too. But my problem is, when I press the home button, and then after a while, I open my app again, the fragment´s m_fragmentdelegate is null!! How can this be possible??

Comment: FYI, I would recommend trying out [the official appcompat library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) instead of Sherlock..

Comment: and why is that? ABS allows my app to show an actionbar in versions below 3.0 while appcompat doesn´t

Comment: appcompat should support API 10+. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968678/gingerbread-devices-not-using-holo-style-from-theme-appcompat-support-library). Granted, it's not perfect, but ABS is more "bloated" than this support library, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm not 100% sure with that, but here's what I think is happening: Android sometimes destroys some of the open views if the app is minimized. When you reopen it, Android tries to restore the App to it's last state and therefore recreates your Fragment. Now, if Android recreates your Fragment, `setFragmentDelegate()` gets of course never called. What I would to to resolve this is to use the Fragments `onAttach()` method instead of setting the listener with `setFragmentDelegate()`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) for an example.